# Hooking into the init action will fire it too frequently?

Tags: hooks, actions, rewrite-rules, customization

> "*Note that I don't recommend hooking the **add_custom_rewrite_rule** into the **init** action as it will fire too frequently. This is just an
>   example. A better place to apply the function would be on theme
>   activation, plugin activate, perhaps the save_post action, etc.
>   Depending on what you need to do, you may only need to fire it once or
>   just a few times.*"

I found this recommendation [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42164/25187). In my WP installation I use a third part plugin that is hooking into the **init** action to change a custom post type slug. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your situation. Whenever you add a rewrite rule and flush the permalinks, it will stay there till the next change/flush of the permalink's settings.

If it's vital for your rules to exist, you can check if it exists on init, and then add it if it's not there. Take a look at [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/184259/94498) answer to get a glimpse of how to check if a rewrite rule exists.

If it's not really necessary for your rules to exist ( for example, you are just doing it for SEO purpose ), you can hook into another action that doesn't run each time a page loads, such as plugin activation.